# Error: undefined is not an object when checking to see if property of object exists

Tags: javascript

Whenever I evaluate my object to see if a property exists, I keep getting the following error message: `Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.result.hasOwnProperty')`.

How can I fix it?

```
    if(++responseCount === products.length) {
      products.sort(function(a, b) {
        if((a.result.hasOwnProperty('rawMisMatchPercentage')) && (b.result.hasOwnProperty('rawMisMatchPercentage'))) {
            return a.result.rawMisMatchPercentage - b.result.rawMisMatchPercentage;
        }
      });
      return products.slice(0, 3);
    }
```

Comment: So a.result is not an object. Make sure it is.

Comment: what is the value of `a.result` ?

Comment: So do I need to do an extra check for `a.result` prior to my check for `a.result.hasOwnProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be

```
(a && a.result && a.result.hasOwnProperty('rawMisMatchPercentage') && (b && 
b.result && b.result.hasOwnProperty('rawMisMatchPercentage'))
```